# How to group a data frame according to multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like the following in R:

```
     V1  V2      V3      V4
 1   81 abc      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 2   81 pqr  deathrock 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 3   81 pqr  goth 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 4   22 abc       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 5   22 uio     retro 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 6   12 xyz     80s 2014-01-01 05:54:54
 7   81 gef      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:55
 8   22 wvy       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 9   12 abc       hit 2014-01-01 05:54:54
 10  12 abc    listen 2014-01-01 05:54:54
```

I want to group the data frame according to column V1 first and then column V3 (all column 1 values are grouped together, and for each unique value of column 1, column 3 values are grouped together) to obtain an output like the following:

```
     V1  V2      V3      V4
 1   81 abc      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 2   81 gef      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:55
 3   81 pqr  goth 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 4   81 pqr  deathrock 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 5   22 abc       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 6   22 wvy       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 7   22 uio     retro 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 8   12 xyz     80s 2014-01-01 05:54:54
 9   12 abc       hit 2014-01-01 05:54:54
 10  12 abc    listen 2014-01-01 05:54:54
```

How would I do it?

I have tried

```
 df = df %>% group_by(V1, V3)
```

but it does not give the right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[order(df$V1, df$V3, decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Output:

```
    V1  V2        V3                  V4
 1: 81 abc      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 2: 81 pqr      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 3: 81 gef      goth 2014-01-01 05:54:55
 4: 81 pqr deathrock 2014-01-01 05:54:21
 5: 22 uio     retro 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 6: 22 abc       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 7: 22 wvy       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:22
 8: 12 abc    listen 2014-01-01 05:54:54
 9: 12 abc       hit 2014-01-01 05:54:54
10: 12 xyz       80s 2014-01-01 05:54:54
```

Comment: But for each unique value in column V1, I would like to order the values of column V3 as well. How would I do that?

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar - See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ***only*** interested in ordering your dataframe use:

```
dfNew = df %>% %>% arrange(V1,V3)
```

But if you are doing calculations by group and need to view results by order use:

```
dfNew = df %>% group_by(V1, V3)%>% arrange(V1,V3)
```

Comment: You don't need the grouping, just `arrange`